# og:image on next 14 site hosted on vercel needs an auth to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have deployed a Next.js 14 site on Vercel. I've put `opengraph-image.png` inside my app folder, next to `layout.tsx`.
When I check the meta tag in  I see this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://ns-website-6pnvd8ili-marek-migas-projects.vercel.app/opengraph-image-12o0cb.png?aadba26415c4ff29">
```

When I try to open that link: https://ns-website-6pnvd8ili-marek-migas-projects.vercel.app/opengraph-image-12o0cb.png?aadba26415c4ff29 it wants me to login to Vercel.
I guess that's the reason why I can't see that og:image ever. Do you know why it needs to auth?

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure why authentication is required for accessing the og:image, but to remove this requirement.

Go to Vercel dashboard settings > Deployment Protection > Vercel Authentication > Disabled